# How to call a kotlin object method(in aar) from java?

Tags: kotlin

An aar file has a kotlin class like

```
package com.material.utils;

object Utils {
    fun init() {
        System.loadLibrary("utils-jni")
    }
}
```

How to call this Utils.init() from a java project that uses this kotlin aar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call it like this

```
Utils.INSTANCE.init();
```